# Can't delete video with vk_api

Tags: python, vk

I want to delete videos from my VK page and i used python with vk_api module.I logged in with my phone number and password, then i do the following:

```py
login, password = 'phone', 'password'
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(
        login, password,
        auth_handler=auth_handler
)

vk_session.auth()

vk = vk_session.get_api()

vid = vk.video.get()

list = vid['items']
for video in list:
    title = video['title']
    id = video['id']    
    print('{} - {}'.format(title, id))
    try:
        vk.video.delete(video_id=id)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

When `vk.video.delete()` called, i have this exception:

`[7] Permission to perform this action is denied`
But `vk.video.get()` working without any exception.

What should i do to get these permissions?

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. Are you able to delete the video manually?

Comment: @ChankeyPathak of course i able to delete them, but there are too many of them to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://vk.com/dev/errors):

> **Permission to perform this action is denied**
>
> Make sure that your have received [required permissions](https://vk.com/dev/permissions) during the authorization. You can do it with the [account.getAppPermissions](https://vk.com/dev/account.getAppPermissions) method